# Error: could not insert 'nvidia_352' after Installing Cuda on EC2 g2.2xlarge

Tags: amazon-ec2, cuda

After launching Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), I tried to install CUDA as following

```
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y cuda
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/bin:$PATH 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo reboot
```

Then I run a test

```
cuda-install-samples-7.5.sh .
cd ~/NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery 
make  
./deviceQuery
```

got the error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Unknown symbol in
>   module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg) cudaGetDeviceCount returned
>   38
>   -> no CUDA-capable device is detected

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Did you found a solution ?

Comment: Try installing CUDA 7 (and a CUDA 7 346.xx driver) instead of CUDA 7.5

Comment: There is an issue with CUDA 7.5 and AWS gpu instances. Seems like Nvidia is looking [into it](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/880246/cuda-7-5-unstable-on-ec2-/). CUDA 7 should work just fine for now.

Comment: @osondoar: You could add that as an answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

Comment: Encountered the same problem, were you able to solve this without downgrading to CUDA 7?

Comment: cuda 7.5 on EC2 g2.2xlarge should now be usable with a 352.63 or later driver.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Do you want upvote the Community wiki answer for this so it falls off the unaswered list (or add your own if you prefer and I'll reciprocate on the vote and delete mine).

Answer (score 10):

Upgrade Ubuntu and install linux-image-extra before install nvidia-driver

`` sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y linux-image-extra-`uname -r` ``

Comment: Have you actually confirmed this works using the CUDA 7.5 release package on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running on an EC2 g2.2xlarge instance?

Comment: This was the solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that this is a [known issue](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/880246/cuda-7-5-unstable-on-ec2-/) within CUDA 7.5 on AWS gpu instances. The short term work around seems to be to downgrade to CUDA 7 for the moment.

---

Edited in December 2015 to add that Robert Crovella from NVIDIA advises that CUDA 7.5 on EC2 g2.2xlarge should now be usable with a 352.63 or later driver. So a driver update should resolve the issue.

[This answer was assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered list]